# Finding jordan basis for a matrix

Tags: jordan-normal-form

I tried to find a Jordan Basis for

$$\begin{pmatrix}3&-1&1&-7\\9&-3&-7&-1\\0&0&4&-8\\0&0&2&-4\end{pmatrix}.$$

I know that Jordan form and eigenvalues are 0 and 0 with eigenvectors being {5,0,6,3} and {1,3,0,0} but I don't know what am I supposed to do next.
What am i supposed to do?

Comment: Kraynov  If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By **Jordan theorem** you know that the **Jordan normal form** is:

$$J=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form

Indeed note that since $A^2=0$,the number of **Jordan blocks of size 2** is;

$$2\cdot \dim(\ker(A^2)-\dim(\ker(A^3)-\dim(\ker(A))=8-4-2=2$$

By Jordan theorem we know that a matrix $P$ exists such that $$P^{-1}AP=J$$

let $$P=[v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4]$$

then P has to satisfy the following system: $$AP=PJ$$ that is in your case $$Av_1=0$$ $$Av_2=v_1$$ $$Av_3=0$$ $$Av_4=v_3$$ you have already found $v_1$ and $v_3$.

Comment: Why do you exclude a priori that $$J=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&1\\ 0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\qquad ?$$

Comment: by Jordan’s theorem https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I’m not so sure that it can be rejected a priori. However, squaring the original matrix gives $0$, so the size of the largest Jordan block is 2.

Comment: @amd You and I could stay here all day finding out reasons to support the fact that a true statement on a $4\times 4$ matrix is true; and it's not our place to do it.

Comment: @amd Yes exactly, in this case the number of Jordan blocks of size 2 is: $$2dim(ker(A^2)-dim(ker(A^3)-dim(ker(A))=8-4-2=2$$.

Comment: Right. So there’s some nontrivial work that you didn’t show that led to your assertion about the form of $J$.

Comment: Yes I've checked by wolfy the result but the method to find J is clear by Jordan theorem which I linked, moreover the OP was about to find the Jordan basis. Anyway I'll add uo some details to the answer.